# Finite difference method LU

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

If R is the region of the plane (0,1) x (0,2), Let L be the 2-d Laplace operator and consider the Poisson equation Lu = 4 on R. One solution is the function v(x,y) = (x-y)^2. Let g be the restriction of v to the boundary of R. To obtain it, we set $h = k = 1/2$, but how to choose m and n? And to solve it, we have to use matlab? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: What do $m$ and $n$ refer to?

Comment: I've updated my question with a picture. m and n refer to how many mesh points that you want to divide the region into.

Comment: Is h and k the step size (spacing between nodes)?

Comment: If you want $h=k=1/2$, starting at zero on the $x$ axis you get to $1$ in two steps, for a total of three points. Starting at zero on the $y$ axis you get to $1$ in four steps, for a total of five points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h$ is your step size in the x-direction and $k$ is your step size in your y-direction, and your boundary is $[a,b]\times [c,d]$, then the number of nodes in the x-direction is 
$$
m  = \frac{b-a}{h} + 1
$$
and the number of nodes in the y-direction is
$$
n = \frac{d-c}{k} + 1.
$$

In your case, you have $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $c = 0$, $d = 2$, $h = k = 1/2$, so

$$
m = \frac{1 - 0}{1/2} + 1= 3
$$

$$
n = \frac{2 - 0}{1/2} + 1= 5.
$$

Comment: Now that we get that $u(x, b), u(x, d), u(a, y) and u(c, y)$, how to compare the correct solution with the approximation? Can we do it by hand instead of Matlab?

Comment: For a quick check, if $u$ is your exact solution, and $u_h$ is your approximation, just take $|u(x,b) - u_h (x,b)|$, and if this is close to zero, your approximation is close to the correct solution for the point $(x,b)$. You can do this for other points too.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give me an example of how to use finite difference method for elliptic equations for finding one of the approximate solution $w_{ij}$?

Comment: It is $u_h(x,b)$ in your case. Thanks!